# Comparing a combined start and end date to determine ordering

Tags: python, date, sorting, dictionary, list-comprehension

With a Python list of dictionaries which always contains `start` and `end` dates, how would you sort the list based on the "combined" `start` and `end` dates?

What would be the simplest (most Pythonic) way to obtain the end result with the following criteria - from top to bottom:

1. Sort by `end_date` (descending) first and then by `start_date` (descending).
2. If there are two objects with the same `end_date`, then the latest `start_date` comes first i.e.: then order by the `start_date` for those items.
3. Should both the `start_date` and the `end_date` be the same, then the ordering of those items is not a concern and can be ignored or remain as is.

```
import datetime


blah = [
    {"id": 1, "start_date": datetime.date(2021, 5, 1), "end_date": None},
    {"id": 2, "start_date": datetime.date(2013, 2, 1), "end_date": None},
    {"id": 3, "start_date": datetime.date(2017, 1, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2018, 1, 1)},
    {"id": 4, "start_date": datetime.date(2016, 5, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2019, 6, 1)},
    {"id": 5, "start_date": datetime.date(2012, 1, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2015, 1, 1)},
    {"id": 6, "start_date": datetime.date(2008, 1, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2011, 1, 1)},
    {"id": 7, "start_date": datetime.date(2006, 1, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2008, 1, 1)},
    {"id": 8, "start_date": datetime.date(2005, 1, 15), "end_date": datetime.date(2010, 1, 15)},
    {"id": 9, "start_date": datetime.date(2002, 1, 15), "end_date": datetime.date(2002, 1, 15)},
    {"id": 10, "start_date": datetime.date(2002, 1, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2006, 1, 1)},
    {"id": 11, "start_date": datetime.date(2002, 1, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2006, 1, 1)},
    {"id": 12, "start_date": datetime.date(2001, 2, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2003, 1, 1)},
    {"id": 13, "start_date": datetime.date(2001, 1, 15), "end_date": datetime.date(2003, 1, 15)},
    {"id": 14, "start_date": datetime.date(1998, 1, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2001, 1, 1)},
    {"id": 15, "start_date": datetime.date(1997, 1, 15), "end_date": datetime.date(1997, 1, 15)}
]

# Do something here...and return `result`.

result = [
    {"id": 1, "start_date": datetime.date(2021, 5, 1), "end_date": None},
    {"id": 2, "start_date": datetime.date(2013, 2, 1), "end_date": None},
    {"id": 4, "start_date": datetime.date(2016, 5, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2019, 6, 1)},
    {"id": 3, "start_date": datetime.date(2017, 1, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2018, 1, 1)},
    {"id": 5, "start_date": datetime.date(2012, 1, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2015, 1, 1)},
    {"id": 6, "start_date": datetime.date(2008, 1, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2011, 1, 1)},
    {"id": 8, "start_date": datetime.date(2005, 1, 15), "end_date": datetime.date(2010, 1, 15)},
    {"id": 7, "start_date": datetime.date(2006, 1, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2008, 1, 1)},
    {"id": 11, "start_date": datetime.date(2002, 1, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2006, 1, 1)},
    {"id": 10, "start_date": datetime.date(2002, 1, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2006, 1, 1)},
    {"id": 9, "start_date": datetime.date(2002, 1, 15), "end_date": datetime.date(2002, 1, 15)},
    {"id": 12, "start_date": datetime.date(2001, 2, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2003, 1, 1)},
    {"id": 13, "start_date": datetime.date(2001, 1, 15), "end_date": datetime.date(2003, 1, 15)},
    {"id": 14, "start_date": datetime.date(1998, 1, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2001, 1, 1)},
    {"id": 15, "start_date": datetime.date(1997, 1, 15), "end_date": datetime.date(1997, 1, 15)}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply sort your data with the appropriate key to satisfy points 1-3; point 4 is automatically satisfied since the sort in Python is guaranteed to be stable:

```
result = sorted(blah,
                reverse = True,
                key=lambda d:(
                    d["end_date"] if d["end_date"] is not None else datetime.date(2999,12,31),
                    d["start_date"])
                )
```

Comment: point 3 will not be satisfied

Comment: Yes, it is. There are no cases in your input, since the only equal end dates are for ids 1 and 2, which are already in the correct order, and for ids 10 and 11, which also have equal start dates. But if you change the start date for id 1, setting it e.g. in 2010, you'll see that id 2 will come before id 1

Comment: Point 3 is just about imposing an natural order on those dates with same `end_date`. I did the following test: `id`s 10 and 11 have same `end_date` and same `start_date`. So if you change the `start_date` of one of the two then it easy to make a test for point 3 (see my `blah` list). `sorted` infers a insertion ordering on `start_date`, not by values

Comment: I don't understand your point: if you change the start date of id 11 (I set it to 2003-05-01) then id 11 appears before id 10 - otherwise 10 appears before 11

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Both @cards answer and this one are suitable candidates to the question.

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the simplest (most Pythonic) way to obtain the end
> result ...

The simplest (most Pythonic) way I can think of would be using pandas.

**Demo:**

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

blah = [
    {"id": 1, "start_date": datetime.date(2021, 5, 1), "end_date": None},
    {"id": 2, "start_date": datetime.date(2013, 2, 1), "end_date": None},
    {"id": 3, "start_date": datetime.date(2017, 1, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2018, 1, 1)},
    {"id": 4, "start_date": datetime.date(2016, 5, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2019, 6, 1)},
    {"id": 5, "start_date": datetime.date(2012, 1, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2015, 1, 1)},
    {"id": 6, "start_date": datetime.date(2008, 1, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2011, 1, 1)},
    {"id": 7, "start_date": datetime.date(2006, 1, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2008, 1, 1)},
    {"id": 8, "start_date": datetime.date(2005, 1, 15), "end_date": datetime.date(2010, 1, 15)},
    {"id": 9, "start_date": datetime.date(2002, 1, 15), "end_date": datetime.date(2002, 1, 15)},
    {"id": 10, "start_date": datetime.date(2002, 1, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2006, 1, 1)},
    {"id": 11, "start_date": datetime.date(2002, 1, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2006, 1, 1)},
    {"id": 12, "start_date": datetime.date(2001, 2, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2003, 1, 1)},
    {"id": 13, "start_date": datetime.date(2001, 1, 15), "end_date": datetime.date(2003, 1, 15)},
    {"id": 14, "start_date": datetime.date(1998, 1, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2001, 1, 1)},
    {"id": 15, "start_date": datetime.date(1997, 1, 15), "end_date": datetime.date(1997, 1, 15)}
]

df = pd.DataFrame(blah)

result = df.sort_values(['end_date', 'start_date'], ascending=(False, False), na_position='first').to_dict('records')

for e in result:
    print(e)
```

**Output:**

```
{'id': 1, 'start_date': datetime.date(2021, 5, 1), 'end_date': None}
{'id': 2, 'start_date': datetime.date(2013, 2, 1), 'end_date': None}
{'id': 4, 'start_date': datetime.date(2016, 5, 1), 'end_date': datetime.date(2019, 6, 1)}
{'id': 3, 'start_date': datetime.date(2017, 1, 1), 'end_date': datetime.date(2018, 1, 1)}
{'id': 5, 'start_date': datetime.date(2012, 1, 1), 'end_date': datetime.date(2015, 1, 1)}
{'id': 6, 'start_date': datetime.date(2008, 1, 1), 'end_date': datetime.date(2011, 1, 1)}
{'id': 8, 'start_date': datetime.date(2005, 1, 15), 'end_date': datetime.date(2010, 1, 15)}
{'id': 7, 'start_date': datetime.date(2006, 1, 1), 'end_date': datetime.date(2008, 1, 1)}
{'id': 10, 'start_date': datetime.date(2002, 1, 1), 'end_date': datetime.date(2006, 1, 1)}
{'id': 11, 'start_date': datetime.date(2002, 1, 1), 'end_date': datetime.date(2006, 1, 1)}
{'id': 13, 'start_date': datetime.date(2001, 1, 15), 'end_date': datetime.date(2003, 1, 15)}
{'id': 12, 'start_date': datetime.date(2001, 2, 1), 'end_date': datetime.date(2003, 1, 1)}
{'id': 9, 'start_date': datetime.date(2002, 1, 15), 'end_date': datetime.date(2002, 1, 15)}
{'id': 14, 'start_date': datetime.date(1998, 1, 1), 'end_date': datetime.date(2001, 1, 1)}
{'id': 15, 'start_date': datetime.date(1997, 1, 15), 'end_date': datetime.date(1997, 1, 15)}
```

Comment: Thank you Arvind Kumar Avinash for this fantastic answer. Although correct, we are accepting a combination of the other answers only because they does not rely on the importing any external libraries i.e.: pandas. (We specifically did not want to limit the use of an external library for this question, which is why we did not mention that restriction in the question). We are sure this will be useful for those making use of pandas!

Answer (score 1):

To order wrt `end_date` I introduced a "fake date" to make the data consistent. This choice is arbitrary but should avoid conflicts with other values. The built-in functions `sorted`, `reversed` need an iterator with homogeneous data, so no `None`.

`sorted` return a list, `reversed` a generator.

```
# In order to make sense the question 3. I modify the start date for 2006, see comment
blah = [
    {"id": 1, "start_date": datetime.date(2021, 5, 1), "end_date": None},
    {"id": 2, "start_date": datetime.date(2013, 2, 1), "end_date": None},
    {"id": 3, "start_date": datetime.date(2017, 1, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2018, 1, 1)},
    {"id": 4, "start_date": datetime.date(2016, 5, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2019, 6, 1)},
    {"id": 5, "start_date": datetime.date(2012, 1, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2015, 1, 1)},
    {"id": 6, "start_date": datetime.date(2008, 1, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2011, 1, 1)},
    {"id": 7, "start_date": datetime.date(2006, 1, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2008, 1, 1)},
    {"id": 8, "start_date": datetime.date(2005, 1, 15), "end_date": datetime.date(2010, 1, 15)},
    {"id": 9, "start_date": datetime.date(2002, 1, 15), "end_date": datetime.date(2002, 1, 15)},
    {"id": 10, "start_date": datetime.date(2002, 1, 2), "end_date": datetime.date(2006, 1, 1)}, # <---- modified start_date!
    {"id": 11, "start_date": datetime.date(2002, 1, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2006, 1, 1)}, 
    {"id": 12, "start_date": datetime.date(2001, 2, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2003, 1, 1)},
    {"id": 13, "start_date": datetime.date(2001, 1, 15), "end_date": datetime.date(2003, 1, 15)},
    {"id": 14, "start_date": datetime.date(1998, 1, 1), "end_date": datetime.date(2001, 1, 1)},
    {"id": 15, "start_date": datetime.date(1997, 1, 15), "end_date": datetime.date(1997, 1, 15)}
]
```

Here the code.

```
import itertools as it
import datetime

FAKE_DATE = datetime.date(2999, 9, 9) # or any non-interfering date 

# 1
print(sorted(blah, key=lambda p: p['start_date']))

print(sorted(blah, reverse=True, key=lambda p: p['start_date'])) # reverse, A
print(list(reversed(sorted(blah, key=lambda p: p['start_date'])))) # reverse, B

# 2
order_2 = reversed(sorted(blah, key=lambda p: p['end_date'] if p['end_date'] is not None else FAKE_DATE))

print(list(order_2))

# 3
grp_by_end_dates = it.groupby(sorted(blah, key=lambda p: p['end_date'] if p['end_date'] is not None else FAKE_DATE), key=lambda p: p['end_date'])
order_3 = it.chain(*(sorted(list(i), reverse=True, key=lambda p: p['start_date']) for _, i in grp_by_end_dates))

print(list(order_3)
```

Comment: @The Go Company I am not sure about 4. and the difference between 1 & 3

Comment: I like both your approaches @cards & @gimix as it does not require any additional external libraries e.g.: pandas. To clarify the difference between points 1 and 2 (edited original question for clarity), by default the ordering is by `end_date` descending (latest first). If however the `end_date` is the same then for those items the default ordering should be by `start_date` descending (latest first). Point 3 simply describes that should both the `start_date` and the `end_date` be the same, then the ordering of those items is not a concern and can be ignored or remain as is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Both @gimix answer and this one are suitable candidates to the question.